# Haskell - My own zip3 function

Tags: list, haskell, zip, tuples

Is there a better way to re-create this function? It compiles fine.

This is what I have:

```
zip3' :: [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [(a,b,c)]
zip3' [] _ _ = []
zip3' _ [] _ = []
zip3' _ _ [] = []
zip3' (a:as) (b:bs) (c:cs) = (a,b,c) : zip3' as bs cs
```

I'm just wondering if there is a better way to summarize this:

```
zip3' [] _ _ = []
zip3' _ [] _ = []
zip3' _ _ [] = []
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It works fine. If you want to make the program shorter, you can write:

```
zip3' :: [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [(a,b,c)]
zip3' (a:as) (b:bs) (c:cs) = (a,b,c) : zip3' as bs cs
zip3' _      _      _ = []
```

Since the first line will only fail to fire if there is at least one of the three lists that is not `(_:_)` (so `[]`). But this is sometimes seen as an anti-pattern, since in a very unlike event that one adds a constructor to the list data type, this might end up with an empty list (whereas in that case, we perhaps better get an error). I agree that for lists this is close to impossible: a lot of libraries and programs would no longer work. But in general it is not uncommon that you for instance design a data type, and later change your mind and add an extra constructor.

If we inspect the source code of [**`zip3 :: [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [(a,b,c)]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip3), then we see it is implemented that way [[source]](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#zip3):

> ```
> zip3 :: [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [(a,b,c)]
> -- Specification
> -- zip3 =  zipWith3 (,,)
> zip3 (a:as) (b:bs) (c:cs) = (a,b,c) : zip3 as bs cs
> zip3 _      _      _      = []
> ```

For some reason `zip` itself is implemented in the "question" style [[source]](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#zip):

> ```
> zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
> zip []     _bs    = []
> zip _as    []     = []
> zip (a:as) (b:bs) = (a,b) : zip as bs
> ```

Comment: Beat me to saying the exact same thing, but you were way more detailed. Well played.

Comment: Looks like the [docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip) specify `zip` to be right-lazy, but `zip3` is under no such restriction. This would explain the discrepancy in implementation, and it also raises an interesting point about the benefit of doing code in the OP's style that I hadn't considered before.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: well as far as I know pattern matching is done left-to-right. So it will also first match the first parameter with `(a:as)`, so afaik, there is no difference in semantics. Anyway, it is funny that we both mention the source code of the Prelude :)

Comment: Hm... I can't seem to construct a counterexample. It seems you're correct about the semantics then.

Comment: The two are equivalent, it seems. https://gist.github.com/Mercerenies/b9174f7ff0bf8637df055b6462ffe917

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing inherently wrong with your approach, but you can collapse the first three cases into a catch-all at the end.

```
zip3' :: [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [(a,b,c)]
zip3' (a:as) (b:bs) (c:cs) = (a,b,c) : zip3' as bs cs
zip3' _ _ _ = []
```

In fact, this is [how GHC does it](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#zip3).